# Order of operations in ActiveRecord lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
 Approval.where("user1_approval IS NOT NULL AND user2_approval IS NOT NULL AND (user_id = ? OR approved_id = ?)", user.id, user.id)
```

I want the part in parenthesis to work -- either of those statements. Currently I get an error on the parenthesis when I run this query.

How can I make this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind to use ActiveRecord query like this ?

```
 Approval.where.not(user1_approval:nil).where.not(user2_approval: nil).where("summoner_id = ? OR approved_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
```

It might reduce the potential problem in writing plain SQL.